# Google is going to deprecate Earth APIs.

Tags: javascript

If Google Earth APIs no longer work after December 12, 2015, will there be any problem for "Google Maps JavaScript API V3"?

Answer (score 0):

No. It should n't. Both are separate API. 
If anybody is wondering how to move from google earth to another api , here is a good article about moving to Cesium: 
http://cesiumjs.org/2014/10/13/youbeQ-Moving-from-Google-Earth-to-Cesium/